# OpenCart 2 - order notification not getting sent to admin

Tags: php, email, opencart, opencart2.x

In OpenCart 2 - the admin never receives a notification when a new order is placed.

The customer always receives this notification, so I'll assume it's not a problem with the sending of mail itself.

The box is checked in the backend, 'New Order Alert Email'.

The mail protocol is set to 'Mail' and the admin email address is in this format:
-Fadmin@sample.com

Does anybody have any advice on this?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Same issue, did you get the solution?